# How can I define a type that maps keys to a generic of that key, e.g. Record<K, SomeGeneric<key>>?

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to do something that seems like it *should* be simple, but I'm at a total loss for how to accomplish it. I'll try to summarise it succinctly here and elaborate on the actual use case below.

I want to create a [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) style structure where the keys map to a value type of `SomeGeneric<K>`, where `K` is the key.

A straightforward way I'd initially try to write this is along the lines of `Record<K, SomeGeneric<K>>`, but that's not a legal type definition: I get “Cannot find name 'K'. ts(2304)”. Naturally this doesn't conceptually work either on re-examination: I'm defining all the keys as type K, and SomeGeneric as corresponding to the key type. There's definitely a more correct way to write this kind of type — but I can't actually figure out what that is. Maybe it's far more complex than I expected, or I'm completely overthinking it. How do I define this type?

### The use case for this structure

The pragmatic reason I want to do this is I'm trying to create a diff between older/newer versions of objects. I'll define a Sprocket interface like this:

```
interface Sprocket {
  name: string;
  fobbed: boolean;
  cycles: number;
}

const older: Sprocket = { name: 'Gizmo', fobbed: true, cycles: 12 };
const newer: Sprocket = { name: 'Gizmo', fobbed: false, cycles: 45 };
```

Now I want to create a diff between the older and newer versions of this sprocket: I want each key to correspond to a value of the form `{ previous: T, current: T }`, where `T` is the value of that key. Essentially like this:

```
interface Sprocket {
  name: { previous: string, current: string };
  fobbed: { previous: boolean, current: boolean};
  cycles: { previous: number, current: number};
}
```

But that's a lot of repetition and I'm essentially redefining the Sprocket interface. Instead I want to make a generic version:

```
interface Diff<T> {
  previous: T;
  current: T;
}

type SprocketValueType<K extends keyof Sprocket> = Sprocket[K];

interface SprocketChanges {
  name: Diff<SprocketValueType<'name'>>;
  fobbed: Diff<SprocketValueType<'fobbed'>>;
  cycles: Diff<SprocketValueType<'cycles'>>;
}
```

So far so good. SprocketValueType reliably gives me the type that corresponds to any given key:

[image]
[image]

And I can supply that to the Diff, so that SprocketChanges picks up the type for that property automatically:

[image]

But I'm still having to manually redefine the keys found in Sprocket. I'd rather define it generically with the Socket interface as the single source of truth on keys *and* types, meaning something like this:

```
type SprocketChanges = Record<K extends keyof Sprocket, Diff<SprocketValueType<K>>;
```

or this:

```
type SprocketChanges = Record<keyof Sprocket, Diff<SprocketValueType<key>>;
```

But neither of these are legal code. The second is even wishing for a magic value `key` that doesn't exist. Both surface a `ts(2304)` error:

[image]

[image]

What type definition **will** work? How can I define this SprocketChanges interface, and map Sprocket's keys to a `Diff<T>` with that key's value?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoAcoHsEGsJjIDeAsAFDLIhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmA3OZTFgEb8IAE0b8sWADYQ4IbhWQIAngmlNGIAK40hUeQF9y5BFhAtkU4dEYZseAsgC8xKrQbIA5AHFgALxpYHgA0yHyCIoysmhAhyqoQ6sgAjABMyPryJmaEIBAA7tZomDj4hM5ErnSM3n4BwaECQqKhcJJMMYoqaowALACs6fLkoJCwiCgAIsAwMAA8ACoAfMQ8yJgQAG7AWJqJ8-KUCJpQUBDgjPvkhmRGZGBK6CgAwgAWsuwJC8vlANoA0shQMh8EosDBkPMALrIRhTGYLf6QxbXcj3R5FbClV7vBJOZDYkAfJizWwlAiLIA) work for you?

Comment: @Eldar Looks like that's exactly what I need! Could you post that as an answer? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution part `type Changes<T> = {[K in keyof T] : Diff<T[K]>}` means map a type that for every key the object has, create a property with a generic `Diff<T>` type that has `T[K]` as type argument which means `typeof Object[Key]`

```
interface Sprocket {
  name: string;
  fobbed: boolean;
  cycles: number;
}

interface Diff<T> {
  previous: T;
  current: T;
}


type Changes<T> = {[K in keyof T] : Diff<T[K]>}

type SproketChanges = Changes<Sprocket>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoAcoHsEGsJjIDeAsAFDLIhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmA3OZTFgEb8IAE0b8sWADYQ4IbhWQIAngmlNGIAK40hUeQF9y5BFhAtkU4dEYZseAsgC8xKrQbIA5AHFgALxpYHgA0yHyCIoysmhAhyqoQ6sgAjABMyPryJmaEIBAA7tZomDj4hM5ErnSM3n4BwaECQqKhcJJMMYoqaowALACs6fLkoJCwiCgAIsAwMAA8ACoAfMQ8yJgQAG7AWJqJ8-KUCJpQUBDgjPvkhmRGZGBK6CgAwgAWsuwJC8vlANoA0shQMh8EosDBkPMALrIRhTGYLf6QxbXcj3R5FbClV7vBJOZDYkAfJizWwlAiLIA)